# In what film/scene was Vulcan calligraphy shown?

Tags: star-trek, languages, vulcan

I'm trying to identify a scene where I seem to remember Vulcan calligraphy was shown, <s>possibly</s> definitely displayed high on a wall or projected into the air. I remember it was quite impressive looking. I found a screenshot [here](https://www.quora.com/Where-online-can-I-translate-English-into-Vulcan) and [here](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a7bc0394fd3dc07401843d7ee5e3b37c?convert_to_webp=true), but these are not high in the air.

Comment: If Vulcan writing was shown anywhere it most likely would have been in the three Enterprise episodes *The Forge*, *Awakening* and/or *Kir'Shara.*

Comment: @Xantec, double check the link I just added.

Comment: You're specifically looking for shots of Vulcan writing from the first J.J. Abrams movie then?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for shots of Vulcan writing either high on a wall or suspended in air, and I *think* it may have been in that film - just like I wrote in the question.

Comment: There is a scene in the *Kir'Shara* episode when Vulcan text is projected into the air above several people's heads ([here](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/startrek/images/2/2b/Kirshara.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070119023652)), but that was hardly recent. Hopefully someone can find additional instances from the first (eleventh) film other than the one you already mentioned.

Comment: Wow - that may indeed be exactly the scene I am looking for! Let me check quickly - if so, could you leave as an answer and I can accept and close?

Comment: @Xantec I remember both of these scenes and they are not the same (the one linked in the question and in the comments). Do you want any instance of Vulcan writing or the specific instance your linked in your question? Netflix took down the J.J. Abrams movies though so I can't verify the exact movie containing your link.

Comment: I've edited the question - I struck out "possibly" and changed to definitely. I just reviewed the scene near the end of the Kir'Shara episode and that is exactly what I'm looking for - *both projected and high!* Unless there's also vulcan projected high in the air in the recent film, I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: @john01dav in the original question, the link was preceded by the word "possibly" and followed by a "?" to indicate that it did not have to be in that film. To avoid confusion, I've edited the question to clarify. There is also [this](http://i.imgur.com/0O8kWgn.gif)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the 2004 Star Trek Enterprise episode [*Kir'Shara*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kir%27Shara) there is a scene towards the end during which Vulcan text is projected above the heads of the people in the room.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! That is *exactly* the scene I am looking for - thank you for sorting it all out for me!

Comment: I think there is also a very brief view of it in Star Trek '09, behind some chemical formula when young Spock is in school.